# Derive the Black– Scholes formula for the European call option.

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance

Consider the standard Black–Scholes model. Derive the Black–
Scholes formula for the European call option.

thanks for help.

Comment: No, this is the SDE for a geometric Brownian motion with drift. The Black-Scholes equation is a partial differential equation for the price. See wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-Scholes_equation

Comment: @LutzL.thanks your right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $dS(t)=rS(t)dt+\sigma S(t)dW(t)$ is not the Black-Scholes formula.  It is a stochastic differential equation for geometric Brownian motion, which is one of the assumptions made in the derivation of the Black-Scholes-Merton pricing formula for an option.

The stock price, $S(t)$, at any future time, is a lognormal random variable -- under the assumption of geometric Brownian motion.

For a call option with strike $K$ that expires at time $T$, the option price at some earlier time $t$ is the expected payoff under the risk-neutral measure (where a more general drift $\mu$ can be replaced by a risk-free rate $r$ as you have already shown.)  This takes the form

$$C[S(t),t] = E_t \{\max[S(T)-K,0]\},$$

where the expectation is conditioned on the information known at time $t$.

Using a dynamic hedging argument, it can be shown that the option price satisfies the Black_Scholes partial differential equation

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} +rS\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}-rC=0,$$

which can be solved in closed form (under suitable assumpions such as constant volatility) for the Black-Scholes option pricing formula.